# Full text search with synonyms

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, indexing, full-text-search

I have a set of strings (now stored in a text file, but it's possible to store it like records in DB, or any other appropriate way). I can recieve a string (searching request) and use it to filter a subset from the set of all strings. Now a string goes in the subset if the exact searching request was found in the string. But I want to improve the filtering process the way that strings goes in the subset if only part of the searching request (meaningful part of a word) or its synonym is found in the string.

How can I get this improvement? I don't want to implement all functionality from scratch. What technology can I use?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do that in a meaningful and performant way.

Comment: If you're looking for a free and publicly available database of English synonyms, check out WordNet: https://wordnet.princeton.edu/